# How do i get shipping method of current Store : Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I am creating functionality to get Shipping methods enabled for selected store.

Currently I am using below code to get Shipping details :

```
$methods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();
$shipMethods = array();

foreach ($methods as $shippigCode=>$shippingModel) 
{

    $shippingTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$shippigCode.'/title');
    $shippingPrice = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$shippigCode.'/price');
    $shippingLabel = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$shippigCode.'/label');
    $shipMethods[]=array('Shipping Type' => $shippigCode, 'title'=> $shippingTitle, 'price'=> $shippingPrice);


}
print_r($shipMethods);
```

I only get config details of the default store.

My question is : **How do i get shipping methods of selected store?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of the function is: `public function getActiveCarriers($store = null)` so you can pass the store as a parameter. You can get the current store with `Mage::app()->getStore()`.